# How to Click or trigger <a href="javascript:viewPage('ABC');> with DOM

Tags: function, dom, triggers, click, href

I'm a beginner, tried to click the link with DOM but didn't worked. how can I click or trigger the function? and why didn't that work?

```
<li id="viewPage"><a href="javascript:viewPage('basic','10000');">viewPage</a>
```

> document.getElementById("viewPage").click()

```
function viewPage(Name,Number){

    $("#ViewPage li").removeClass("active");
    $("#"+Name).addClass("active");

    $("#ViewPage").load(
        Name+".asp",
        {
            Number : Number 
        },
        function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "there was an error: ";
                $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: What button? You mean the link?

Comment: yes the link in the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't seem to mind using jquery in the rest of your code, here is an easy way to get the click using jquery:

```js
$('#viewPage').click(function() {
  console.log('Now your click function is working');
});

function viewPage1(Name, Number) {

  $("#ViewPage1 li").removeClass("active");
  $("#" + Name).addClass("active");

  $("#ViewPage1").load(
    Name + ".asp", {
      Number: Number
    },
    function(response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "there was an error: ";
        $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="viewPage"><a href="javascript:viewPage1('basic','10000');">viewPage1</a>
```

Comment: oh,, i'm sorry that was my typing error in copying the source and i edited it. my point is "document.getElementbyId("viewPage1").click() doesn't work..

Comment: You aren't defining a function inside click.

Comment: How can i do that?.. maybe this "click("viewPage1")" work?